# Prolog - Iterate through matrix

Tags: matrix, grid, prolog

Just want to warn you that I am very new with Prolog, and do not even know where to start.

First of I need to create a grid of 3x3. Then I need to iterate through it and print out the current square I am on.

So the grid would look like:

```
[6],[7],[8]
[5],[4],[3]
[0],[1],[2]
```

My lecturer is not giving any examples and I don't know where else to turn.

Comment: I would represent the grid as a list of lists.

Comment: As far as the concept of representation, it's not that different than any other language. In C, for example, you'd represent a 2D matrix as an array of rows, and each row would be an array of column values. In Prolog, each row would be a list of column values, and the matrix would be a list of rows (a list of lists as @VaughnCato said). If you don't know much about how Prolog lists work, I'd recommend Google and find a good tutorial. They're as fundamental to Prolog as pointers are to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your grid is going to look like this:

```
Grid = [[6,7,8],[5,4,3],[0,1,2]].
```

I am fond of this predicate for accessing a matrix:

```
matrix(Matrix, I, J, Value) :-
    nth0(I, Matrix, Row),
    nth0(J, Row, Value).
```

This gives you a relationship between a matrix, the column index, row index and the value at that location. It's important that you think of this as a *relationship*, because it can do many things for you:

1. Get the value at a given coordinate in the matrix:

   ```
   ?- Grid = [[6,7,8],[5,4,3],[0,1,2]], matrix(Grid, 1, 1, Value).
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   Value = 4.
   ```
2. Iterate the matrix:

   ```
   ?- Grid = [[6,7,8],[5,4,3],[0,1,2]], matrix(Grid, I, J, Value).
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = J, J = 0,
   Value = 6 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = 0,
   J = 1,
   Value = 7 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = 0,
   J = 2,
   Value = 8 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = 1,
   J = 0,
   Value = 5 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = J, J = 1,
   Value = 4 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = 1,
   J = 2,
   Value = 3 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = 2,
   J = Value, Value = 0 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = 2,
   J = Value, Value = 1 ;
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   I = J, J = Value, Value = 2.
   ```
3. Select a row from the matrix:

   ```
   ?- Grid = [[6,7,8],[5,4,3],[0,1,2]], 
      findall(Value, matrix(Grid, 1, _, Value), Row).
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   Row = [5, 4, 3].
   ```
4. Select a column from the matrix:

   ```
   ?- Grid = [[6,7,8],[5,4,3],[0,1,2]], 
      findall(Value, matrix(Grid, _, 1, Value), Column).
   Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]],
   Column = [7, 4, 1].
   ```
5. Construct a new matrix(!):

   ```
   ?- matrix(M, 0, 0, 4), matrix(M, 1, 1, 2).
   M = [[4|_G673], [_G678, 2|_G682]|_G676].
   ```

Really, this one predicate makes it possible to do it all, because it just establishes the structure of the matrix, floating out the values that might be interesting to a caller and letting Prolog's backtracking do the rest.

This list representation is not as efficient as a matrix in C, but you can't let that get you down: you're using Prolog!

If you were really upset about list performance, you could do the same thing but change your structure to use `arg/3` and terms instead of lists. The neat thing is, you could probably keep `matrix/4`'s API the same after the change! But you may lose #5 up there.

So, to display all the values in the matrix now is quite trivial:

```
display_matrix(Matrix) :-
    matrix(Matrix, I, J, Value),
    write('I am on square ('),
    write(I), write(','), write(J),
    write(') and the value is '), write(Value), nl,
    fail.
display_matrix(_).
```

And let's try it:

```
?- Grid = [[6,7,8],[5,4,3],[0,1,2]], 
   display_matrix(Grid).
I am on square (0,0) and the value is 6
I am on square (0,1) and the value is 7
I am on square (0,2) and the value is 8
I am on square (1,0) and the value is 5
I am on square (1,1) and the value is 4
I am on square (1,2) and the value is 3
I am on square (2,0) and the value is 0
I am on square (2,1) and the value is 1
I am on square (2,2) and the value is 2
Grid = [[6, 7, 8], [5, 4, 3], [0, 1, 2]].
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are the best! Thank you. :)